# How to convert UTF-8 to String in Java

Tags: java, android

I am stuck here because after making the convertion from byte to String I works with append method but if I want to use setText instead of append, I get no text shown on my phone. And I don't want to write text next to the last one.

```
UsbSerialInterface.UsbReadCallback mCallback = new UsbSerialInterface.UsbReadCallback() { 
        @Override
        public void onReceivedData(byte[] arg0) {
            String data = null;
             try {
                data = new String(arg0 , "UTF-8");
                    tvAppend(mostrarEntradaAnalogica, data);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }


        }
    };

public void tvAppend(TextView tv, String text) {
        final TextView ftv = tv;
        final String ftext = text;


        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ftv.append(ftext);
            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: What is your code when you use `setText()`?

Comment: When I use setText() i get no text shown on my phone. I've been trying it in many ways

Comment: Change the method arguments to be `final` (`tvAppend(final TextView tv, final String text)`) and remove the reassignments.

Comment: I've tried this bro, but still the same error.

final void tvAppend(final TextView tv, final String text) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tv.setText(text);
            }
        });
    }

Comment: You could try running `setText(null)` and then the text you want.

Comment: Also not working bro :(